# Coliru alternative for C to use on SO

Tags: discussion, external-links

Is there a commonly used online C editor and compiler that is, or can be, linked to in SO answers?

I understand that Coliru works well for C++, however it does not allow for `--std` to be set equal to any C only setting (i.e. not C++). This makes it less than ideal for use.

Comment: Hmm? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8392c2a75091810

Comment: Hmm no. 2? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3957ae4516384f87 :P

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware this level of access was avialble - most of these systems do not allow such so I didnt even try! XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coliru can run arbitrary commands as if in bash. Almost everything is allowed (network access is a notable exception).

GCC usually determines the language from the file name, so using the default main.cpp file in Coliru causes a message to be printed about this. If you rename the file to main.c before compilation, or pass the `-xc` flag to force it to use C, it works without that warning message.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a46d2dc851a381a

Answer (score 6):

The only problem is that the file name is `main.cpp`, so you have to override the GCC preference of using C++ for `.cpp` extension: C can be used with `-x c` option.

`gcc -x c -std=c11 main.cpp && ./a.out` should be enough to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Ideone](https://ideone.com/) and [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) when I need a C online compiler.

Ideone is very basic and doesn't let you configure a lot(any) of the settings.

Wandbox gives you basically full reign on the compilation and also allows you to use multiple files.

Generally I use Wandbox if I want to do anything more then just seeing if something will compile.